# How to pull out just the capitalized words and 1..3 words on either side of that capitalized word in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to:

- find the words that are capitalized.
- extract each of those words into an element in an array.
- also extract 1 - 3 words before & after the initial word, as part of the same element.

Also, I'd like to:

- De-duplicate elements - I know this may lead to some duplication. That's fine. I can sort through that later. Ideally I would like to not have duplication, so if there is a way to de-dupe it right here, then that would be awesome but it's not the main focus.
- There will be some instances where a capitalized word is followed by some punctuation or symbol, and so the words after the symbol should NOT be included in that array element.

---

If I have a string `words`:

```
Welcome\r\n        About\r\n    Hello, I'm John Van der Lyn and welcome to our website. We try to tailor our services to your specific needs, provide personal attention and someone to call with answers to your tax and financial questions and issues throughout the year. We believe in establishing long-term relationships with our clients and in providing good ole fashion service.\r\n            \r\n\r\n     We provide all levels of services for individuals with their tax and financial needs as well as Personal Representatives of Estates, or Trustees or beneficiaries of
```

An acceptable array result looks like this:

```
["Welcome About Hello", "Welcome About Hello I'm", "About Hello I'm John", "Hello I'm John Van", "I'm John Van der Lyn", etc.]
```

A better, more ideal result looks like this:

```
["Welcome About Hello", "I'm John Van der Lyn", "We try to", etc.]
```

A perfect and exceptional (although much more complicated) result looks like this:

```
["Welcome", "About", "Hello", "I'm John Van der Lyn", etc.]
```

I tried using `split`, but I can't figure out how to pass a regex to `split` the string per the rules of the regex. I also couldn't figure out how to split it into chunks of say four words per element, than just one word.

Comment: What do you mean by "...extract 1-3 words before and after...". When would it be 1, 2 or 3? In your "perfect" result you have 4 words following "I'm" and none before. Where are the words "before" "I'm"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was thinking when the words are present. For instance, at the beginning of the document, there are no words before the first word. If the second word is capitalized, the only 1 word would be available to be pulled from before the word in question, etc. Perhaps I could have phrased that better, but that's what I meant.

Comment: ... and what's the difference between `Hello About Hello` and `John Van`?? Why is the first case split and not the second? Also, why do you capture `We try to` instead of `We try to tailor` (with 3 words afterwards)?

Comment: This is what I interpreted from your question http://rubular.com/r/mLBvmrYC5t but I'm voting to close this question as *not clear what you're asking*

Comment: @Mariano what I am really trying to do is extract names from each page I crawl. However, there isn't an easy way to differentiate a name for any other word other than comparing it to a names database to see if this word is a name. All names are usually capitalized, but some names have names that start with common letters, e.g. `John Van der Lyn`. That's the goal of everything I am trying here. So the way I was looking at it is, if there is a capitalized word, if it is a name, then the next 1, 2 or 3 words may be part of the same name. So I want to just capture all and filter after.

Comment: @marcamillion Perhaps if you excluded newlines from the accepted whitespace or, even better, if you only accepted 1 space between words. There is no efficient way to match a name (not to mention international names that may have no capitalization at all), so I'd recommend setting accurate rules for what you want it to match.

Comment: There's no perfect algorithm for this. You're trying to replace an expert system or AI with a one-line regex. No soup for you! :)

Comment: You need to think about narrowing this down and defining it better. Currently it's not clear what you want, nor do you show how you attempted to solve it. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code demonstrating what you tried which helps narrow down the problem. All you've given is your needs but no examples of your effort. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)” will help explain what we expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = str.scan(/([\w\'\-]+)*/).flatten.compact

>> ["Welcome", "About", "Hello", "I'm", "John", "Van", "der", "Lyn", "and", "welcome", "to", "our", "website", "We", "try", "to", "tailor", "our", "services", "to", "your", "specific", "needs", "provide", "personal", "attention", "and", "someone", "to", "call", "with", "answers", "to", "your", "tax", "and", "financial", "questions", "and", "issues", "throughout", "the", "year", "We", "believe", "in", "establishing", "long-term", "relationships", "with", "our", "clients", "and", "in", "providing", "good", "ole", "fashion", "service", "We", "provide", "all", "levels", "of", "services", "for", "individuals", "with", "their", "tax", "and", "financial", "needs", "as", "well", "as", "Personal", "Representatives", "of", "Estates", "or", "Trustees", "or", "beneficiaries", "of"]

words.each_with_index do |word, i|
  if word[0].match(/[A-Z]/)
    tmp = []
    tmp << words[i-2] unless i-2 < 0
    tmp << words[i-1] unless i-1 < 0
    tmp << word
    tmp << words[i+1]
    tmp << words[i+2]
    word_groups << tmp
  end
end

>> [["Welcome", "About", "Hello"], ["Welcome", "About", "Hello", "I'm"], ["Welcome", "About", "Hello", "I'm", "John"], ["About", "Hello", "I'm", "John", "Van"], ["Hello", "I'm", "John", "Van", "der"], ["I'm", "John", "Van", "der", "Lyn"], ["Van", "der", "Lyn", "and", "welcome"], ["our", "website", "We", "try", "to"], ["the", "year", "We", "believe", "in"], ["fashion", "service", "We", "provide", "all"], ["well", "as", "Personal", "Representatives", "of"], ["as", "Personal", "Representatives", "of", "Estates"], ["Representatives", "of", "Estates", "or", "Trustees"], ["Estates", "or", "Trustees", "or", "beneficiaries"]]

word_groups.map { |grp| grp.join(' ') }

>> ["Welcome About Hello", "Welcome About Hello I'm", "Welcome About Hello I'm John", "About Hello I'm John Van", "Hello I'm John Van der", "I'm John Van der Lyn", "Van der Lyn and welcome", "our website We try to", "the year We believe in", "fashion service We provide all", "well as Personal Representatives of", "as Personal Representatives of Estates", "Representatives of Estates or Trustees", "Estates or Trustees or beneficiaries"]
```

Comment: So strictly speaking, you have done what I asked. It's a bit cumbersome though. I was hoping it could be done with a simple regex, or some other ruby method like `split` or something else. I do like the direction though.

Answer (score 0):

1. This has probably no solution.
2. If you have a strict pattern for how to match the name, it is more or less solvable.

Let’s pretend we have a matcher for a name. In our case it would be: the name contains `4` words at most, at least `2` of them are capitalized (first and last) and names can’t contain weird symbols like “.”.

```
matcher = ->(words) do
  words.first =~ /\A\p{Lu}/ && # first in capitalized
  words.last =~ /\A\p{Lu}/ &&  # last in capitalized
  words.all?(&/\A\p{L}+\z/.method(:=~)) # letters only
end
```

Here we use proper unicode [character matchers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties). Now we can sieve our input:

```
(2..4).map { |i| input.split(/\s+/).each_cons(i).select(&matcher) }
      .reduce(&:|)
```

The above will return

```
#⇒ [["Welcome", "About"], ["John", "Van"], 
#   ["Personal", "Representatives"], ["Van", "der", "Lyn"], 
#   ["John", "Van", "der", "Lyn"]]
```

Now we can remove “weak” dups, but I’d have left this as a homework.

Comment: I agree with "1.". It's not a well-defined question.